# Tomcat 6.0.18 gets stuck after some while

Tags: tomcat6

After some while, Tomcat (6.0.18) gets stuck:
When I did netstat -an | grep 8080 everything seems stuck!
For example, recv-Q and send-Q remain with the same numbers.

and when I try to 
run a simple Http client code:

```
URL u = new java.net.URL("http://localhost:8080/my/test")
c = u.openConnection();
c.getInputStream();
```

The client waits (until timeout) during getInputStream.

Any known issues with 6.0.18?
Any parameters I should check?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can fire up Visual VM and check out memory generations, especially perm gen, and threads.  I'd try that.  Be sure to install all the plugins for maximum information.  Just start up Visual VM and attach it to the Tomcat PID.

A Google search of "Tomcat 6 hangs" brought back bunches:

http://www.tomcatexpert.com/ask-the-experts/tomcat-hang-after-a-random-period-of-time